# Совместить команды в vim в map

Tags: vim

подскажите, если кто знает.

Прописал для vim следующий map:
map  :!clear;nasm -fbin -o prog.obj %

Но часто встаёт ситуация, что до этой клавиши нужно сохранять код. (:w)

Можно ли внести в данный map сохранение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map <F5> :w<CR>:!clear;nasm -fbin -o prog.obj %<CR>
```